# MySQL insert multiple rows with one select

Tags: mysql, select, rows

I run the following query multiple times:

```
insert ignore into temp_table (ID, Price, Stock, Vendor)
select ID, Price_Vendor_A, Stock_Vendor_A, 'Vendor_A' from temp_table2 limit 1;
insert ignore into temp_table (ID, Price, Stock, Vendor)
select ID, Price_Vendor_B, Stock_Vendor_B, 'Vendor_B' from temp_table2 limit 1;
```

The 2 select queries are leading to the same row.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following will be the fastest way. elimincates multiple selects.

```
 SELECT ID, Price_Vendor_A, Stock_Vendor_A,Price_Vendor_B, Stock_Vendor_B into @ID, @Price_Vendor_A,@Stock_Vendor_A,@Price_Vendor_B,@Stock_Vendor_B FROM temp_table2 LIMIT 1;

insert ignore into temp_table (ID, Price, Stock, Vendor) SELECT @ID as ID, @Price_Vendor_A as price, @Stock_Vendor_A as stock ,"Vendor_A" AS Vendor UNION ALL  SELECT @ID as ID, @Price_Vendor_B as price, @Stock_Vendor_B as stock ,"Vendor_B" AS Vendor
```

Comment: The query seems to work, but this only creates two row, with the stock and prices of vendor A. How can I use your query to create two rows, one with vendor A and one with vendor B?

Comment: Oops , can you tell me where are using this sql ?. In code or in procedure / function / sql editor ?

Comment: I create a procedure in MySQL. My sqleditor is called HeidiSQL.

Comment: Works like a charm, increased the speed a lot.  Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be faster, but you could try inserting a single `UNION` query:

```
insert ignore into temp_table (ID, Price, Stock, Vendor)
select ID, Price_Vendor_A, Stock_Vendor_A, 'Vendor_A' from temp_table2 limit 1
union all
select ID, Price_Vendor_B, Stock_Vendor_B, 'Vendor_B' from temp_table2 limit 1
```